# Concatenate two strings using memcpy

Tags: c

I am trying to make a function that concatenates two strings without using `strncat`/`strcat` in C. I have this, but it gives a segfault error. What am I doing wrong?

```
char *concat(char *str1, char *str2) {
    memcpy(str1 + strlen(str1) - 1, str2, strlen(str2) + 1);
    return str1;
}
```

This is not homework. It's for the C toolchain for TI-84 Plus CE and `strncat` doesn't work for me in this function. `str1` will be a string literal. `str2` will be variable.

Comment: Are you sure there is enough space at the end of `str1` for the new chars? This function will not work if `str1` is a static string, just like `strcat`...

Comment: *"`str1` will be a string literal."* You cannot modify a string literal, that might be why `strncat` isn't working either

Comment: Why not allocate new space which is large enough to hold the concatenation?

Comment: I don't know how to do these things because I am new to C, but that sounds like the problem. I will be using the function like this: `concat("Hello ", world);` where `world` is a variable.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to ensure that `str1` points to a memory location big enough to receive the entire result :

```
char *concat(char const*str1, char const*str2) {
   size_t const l1 = strlen(str1) ;
   size_t const l2 = strlen(str2) ;

    char* result = malloc(l1 + l2 + 1);
    if(!result) return result;
    memcpy(result, str1, l1) ;
    memcpy(result + l1, str2, l2 + 1);
    return result;
}
```

Additionally, you should add error checking, as much as possible, at least some `assert(str1) ; assert(str2) ;`...

Comment: I'd skip the asserts and just let it crash if any of the strings are NULL. The asserts wouldn't buy much in this context.

Comment: The asserts actually asure that your program crashes - right at the place where you paced them. Youu cant be sure that your program crashes right away if you write to /read data from an invalid address, unfortunately. - maybe it just exhibits weird and hard to debug behavior. Nb:in production code (`DEBUG`not defined) the asserts won't yield any code, thus no overhead either. But I'm just suggesting...

Comment: Another option would be to decide that passing in a NULL is the same as passing in "" and making that substitution.

Answer (score 2):

Your function implements `strcat` in a simple and straight forward way with the same restrictions, but it has a bug: you are copying the contents of `str2` one byte after the end of the string in `str1`. Remove the `+ 1` in the first argument to `memcpy`. Note that you can make `str2` a `const char *` as you are not modifying the contents of the array it points to.

```
char *concat(char *str1, const char *str2) {
    memcpy(str1 + strlen(str1), str2, strlen(str2) + 1);
    return str1;
}
```

If the destination array is a *string literal*, you cannot use this approach as attempting to modify string literals has undefined behavior. You should first copy the string literal into an array large enough to accommodate both strings and the null terminator.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
char *str1="hello";
char *str2=" world";
char *str3;

str3=(char *) malloc (11 *sizeof(char));
memcpy(str3,str1,5);
memcpy(str3+strlen(str1),str2,6);

printf("%s + %s = %s",str1,str2,str3);
free(str3);
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!